# Excel VBA: Optimizing Worksheet_Change function to avoid "Not enough system resource to display completely"

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

First I need to say that I a beginner with VBA. I understand VBA basics and I already did some little projects but most of it involved a lot of googling.

For the current issue, I could not find any useful tips online. Maybe it's because I created the code on my own. But see for yourself...

I am trying to create a table with client data. The table contains the client number in `column "I"` which is being added by hand. The table should now pick up other client data such as domicile, age, etc automatically based on the client number from a static database that is in another tab. However, I want to have the possibility to manually overwrite the cells in my table that contain the client data from the database. But when I delete my manual entries the original data from the database should appear again.

With the code below I was able to do this. When a cell is empty the code adds a `formula` to the cell that picks up the data from the database. However, I am able to overwrite the `formula` manually. When I delete my manual entry and the cell becomes empty again the `formula` appears again and picks up the data from the database. But I have two problems with the code below:

1. The code seems to be too "heavy". For example, when I delete rows, I get an error message `"Not enough system resource to display completely"` which freezes the complete Excel file.
2. When I add new client numbers in `column "I"` the code does not pick up the data from the database automatically. I need to trigger the `Worksheet_Change` for every single cell by choosing the cell and clicking `Delete`

So I am looking for a way to simplify my code so that:

1. the error message does not occur again when I am deleting rows;
2. when I add a new client number in `column "I"` the other cells in the same row should instantly pickup other client data from the database.

I already tried the following but without success:

1. To delete rows I created a code that does it automatically and I added `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of the code and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end with the intention to stop the `Worksheet_Change` while the rows are being deleted but it did not work and I still got an error.
2. To trigger the `Worksheet_Change` I used the following code `Application.Run "Sheet3.Worksheet_Change", Range("A1:Z5000")` and assigned it to a button but it did not work.

So here is the existing code (note the code look longer than it is. The code for every column is the same, only the `formulas` is different that is being put into the cells are different):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Code for column B
Dim AffectedRange As Range
Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:B" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In AffectedRange.Cells

            If iCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell.Row & "="""","""",VLOOKUP($I" & iCell.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,4,FALSE)),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell
End If

'Code for column D
Dim AffectedRange1 As Range
Set AffectedRange1 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D2:D" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange1 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell1 As Range
    For Each iCell1 In AffectedRange1.Cells

            If iCell1.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell1.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell1.Row & "="""","""",IF(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell1.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,9,FALSE)=0,""N/A"",VLOOKUP($I" & iCell1.Row & ", 'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,9,FALSE))),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell1
End If

'Code for column E
Dim AffectedRange2 As Range
Set AffectedRange2 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E2:E" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange2 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell2 As Range
    For Each iCell2 In AffectedRange2.Cells

            If iCell2.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell2.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell2.Row & "="""","""",IF(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell2.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,10,FALSE)=0,""N/A"",VLOOKUP($I" & iCell2.Row & ", 'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,10,FALSE))),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell2
End If

'Code for column C
Dim AffectedRange4 As Range
Set AffectedRange4 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C2:C" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange4 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell4 As Range
    For Each iCell4 In AffectedRange4.Cells

            If iCell4.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell4.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell4.Row & "="""","""",IF(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell4.Row & ",'Raw Data'!A$1:$AH$5000,22,FALSE)=0,""N/A"",IF(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell4.Row & ",'Raw Data'!A$1:$AH$5000,22,FALSE)<0.49999,""Prio 3"",IF(AND(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell4.Row & ",'Raw Data'!A$1:$AH$5000,22,FALSE)>0.49999,VLOOKUP($I" & iCell4.Row & ",'Raw Data'!A$1:$AH$5000,22,FALSE)<0.79999),""Prio 2"",IF(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell4.Row & ",'Raw Data'!A$1:$AH$5000,22,FALSE)>0.79999,""Prio 1"",""N/A""))))),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell4
End If

'Code for column H
Dim AffectedRange5 As Range
Set AffectedRange5 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H2:H" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange5 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell5 As Range
    For Each iCell5 In AffectedRange5.Cells

            If iCell5.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell5.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell5.Row & "="""","""",IF(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell5.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,11,FALSE)=0,""N/A"",VLOOKUP($I" & iCell5.Row & ", 'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,11,FALSE))),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell5
End If

'Code for column F
Dim AffectedRange6 As Range
Set AffectedRange6 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F2:F" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange6 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell6 As Range
    For Each iCell6 In AffectedRange6.Cells

            If iCell6.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell6.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell6.Row & "="""","""",(IF(OR($D" & iCell6.Row & "=""N/A"",$D" & iCell6.Row & "=""""),""N/A"",IF(AND($H" & iCell6.Row & "=""Espagne"",LEN($D" & iCell6.Row & ")=5),VLOOKUP(LEFT($D" & iCell6.Row & ",2),Regionslist!$A$1:$B$52,2,FALSE),IF(AND($H" & iCell6.Row & "=""Espagne"",LEN($D" & iCell6.Row & ")=4),VLOOKUP(""0""&LEFT($D" & iCell6.Row & ",1),Regionslist!$A$1:$B$52,2,FALSE),$H" & iCell6.Row & "))))),$H" & iCell6.Row & ")"
        End If
    Next iCell6
End If

'Code for column G
Dim AffectedRange7 As Range
Set AffectedRange7 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G2:G" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange7 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell7 As Range
    For Each iCell7 In AffectedRange7.Cells

            If iCell7.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell7.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell7.Row & "="""","""",VLOOKUP($F" & iCell7.Row & ",Regionslist!$B$1:$C$52,2,FALSE)),$F" & iCell7.Row & ")"
        End If
    Next iCell7
End If

'Code for column J
Dim AffectedRange8 As Range
Set AffectedRange8 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J2:J" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange8 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell8 As Range
    For Each iCell8 In AffectedRange8.Cells

            If iCell8.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell8.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell8.Row & "="""","""",VLOOKUP($I" & iCell8.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,2,FALSE)),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell8
End If

'Code for column K
Dim AffectedRange9 As Range
Set AffectedRange9 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("K2:K" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange9 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell9 As Range
    For Each iCell9 In AffectedRange9.Cells

            If iCell9.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell9.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell9.Row & "="""","""",IF(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell9.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,13,FALSE),"","","""")<>"""",SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell9.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,13,FALSE),"","",""""),""N/A"")),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell9
End If

'Code for column L
Dim AffectedRange10 As Range
Set AffectedRange10 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L2:L" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange10 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell10 As Range
    For Each iCell10 In AffectedRange10.Cells

            If iCell10.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell10.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell10.Row & "="""","""",SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell10.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,20,FALSE),"","","""")),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell10
End If

'Code for column M
Dim AffectedRange11 As Range
Set AffectedRange11 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M2:M" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange11 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell11 As Range
    For Each iCell11 In AffectedRange11.Cells

            If iCell11.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell11.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell11.Row & "="""","""",VLOOKUP($I" & iCell11.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,22,FALSE)),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell11
End If

'Code for column N
Dim AffectedRange12 As Range
Set AffectedRange12 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("N2:N" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange12 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell12 As Range
    For Each iCell12 In AffectedRange12.Cells

            If iCell12.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell12.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($I" & iCell12.Row & "="""","""",""1.""&VLOOKUP($I" & iCell12.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,21,FALSE)),""N/A"")"
        End If
    Next iCell12
End If

'Code for column W
Dim AffectedRange13 As Range
Set AffectedRange13 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("W2:W" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange13 Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell13 As Range
    For Each iCell13 In AffectedRange13.Cells

            If iCell13.Value = vbNullString Then
            iCell13.Formula = "=IF($I" & iCell13.Row & "="""","""",IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($I" & iCell13.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,1,FALSE)=$I" & iCell13.Row & ",""yes"",""no""),""no""))"
        End If
    Next iCell13
End If
End sub
```

In advance many thanks for any kind of advice and help!

Best regards,
Oliver

Comment: Looks like your handler is re-entrant; `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top, `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the bottom.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon What would that mean if it is re-entrant? My though behind this was that I turn the `Worksheet_Change` off while I run the other code that deletes the rows and once the rows are deleted the `Worksheet_Change` should work again. But maybe I made a thinking error...

Comment: Sorry I admittedly didn't read the whole wall of text.... basically without disabling worksheet events, a `Worksheet_Change` handler that modifies the sheet it's being triggered for, is going to recurse. If the recursion goes deeper than VBA can handle, expect Excel to outright crash: you *must* prevent re-firing the event from its handler... whether or not the recursion is related to the problem at hand.

Comment: You code doesn't check for changes in Col I, so you could add a block for that.

Comment: Sorry was out of office so I could work on the file. I am just thinking about to change the whole ´Worksheet_Change´ sub to a regular sub that can be activated with a button. Would that work? And if so how to I need to change the ´Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I2:I" & Me.Rows.Count))´ part?

Comment: Found a way to stop the the error. Instead of ´Application.EnableEvents = True´ and ´Application.EnableEvents = False´ I used the solution described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637435/how-to-unable-worksheet-change-from-excel-vba-if-macro-is-enabled/43637544

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code doesn't check for changes in Col I, so you could add a block for that

```
'Code for column B
Dim AffectedRange As Range
Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I2:I" & Me.Rows.Count))

If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In AffectedRange.Cells
        Application.EnableEvents=false
        'Note the Range is *relative* to EntireRow
        iCell.EntireRow.range("B1:H1,J1:M1").value = 1 'set an initial value
        Application.EnableEvents=True
        'Then trigger a change to set the formulas
        iCell.EntireRow.range("B1:H1,J1:M1").ClearContents
    Next iCell
End I
```